# django test for upload image

Tags: django, django-tests

i want to test user registration but i can't  test image here is my test:

test.py

```
response = self.client.post('/api/v1/signup/',
                                content_type='application/json',
                                data=json.dumps({"username": "casino", "email": "casinoluxwin@gmail.com",
                                                 "password1": "android12", "password2": "android12", "photo": {
                                                            'real_filename': "u'banner3.jpg'",
                                                            'path': "u'C:/Users/Dima/Desktop'"}

                                                 }))
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

i get code 400(bad request), but  without photo my test pass

```
service/users.py

 @validate_input({
    'username': {'min_length': 3, 'max_length': 50},
    'email': {'validation_type': "email", 'max_length': 50},
    'password1': {'min_length': 8, 'max_length': 50},
    'password2': {'min_length': 8, 'equal_to': 'password1',
                  'messages': {'equal_to': _(u"Пароли не совпадают")}},
    'photo': {'required': True}
})
@transaction.atomic
def signup(self, data):
    user_data = {
        'username': data['username'],
        'email': data['email'],
        'password': data['password1'],
        'coins_amount': 0
    }
    user = self._create_user(user_data)
    if data.get("photo"):
        self._attach_photo(user, data["photo"])

    obj, created = VerificationCode.objects.get_or_create(user=user, code_type="registration")
    obj.create_expiration_date()
    obj.create_code()
    obj.save()

    return user.id
```

So i want to test user photo anything else works fine. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Problem probably resides in either `Users._attach_photo()` or your user model. Not  enough information here to decipher it entirely. There are a couple of things to try.

I'd write a normal unittest that does not use the client. It'll give you a more helpful traceback than just the HTTP status code from the running server. Something like:

```
    def test_user_add_method(self):
        x = Users.signup(json.dumps({"username": "casino", "email": "casinoluxwin@gmail.com",
                                             "password1": "android12", "password2": "android12", "photo": {
                                                        'real_filename': "u'banner3.jpg'",
                                                        'path': "u'C:/Users/Dima/Desktop'"})
    Users.get(pk=x) #will fail if user was not created.
```

Second, try commenting out your validator. 400 bad request could easily be kicked off by that. It is possible that your validator isn't playing nice with the image and you'll have to mess around with that.

Comment: doesn't work but thanks, i found problem  i can't load image but test pass and user is create without photo, thi is problem :     SuspiciousFileOperation: Attempted access to  'C:/Users/Dima/Desktop/banner3.jpg' denied